Are there known changes to <InputFile/> that makes OnChange crash app in .NET 9?
I'm trying to add a simple filepicker to a Blazor .NET 9 app, but it crashes. The code is simply:
<InputFile OnChange="HandleSelection" />

@code {
private async Task HandleSelection(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    var file = e.File;
}}

This works fine in .NET 8, but causes a crash in .NET 9 with error:

The program '[36348] BlazorApp4.exe' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff).

Is there a known fix for this?
TIA!
Dennis

Template: Blazor Server: Interactivity Global .  Doesn't crash.  What's your configuration?

I use <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" /> in App.razor for my real project, but for the empty test project I used the default Blazor Web App Server template (VS2022) and I put @rendermode InteractiveServer in the page. No dice...

My Test project that works as advertised. https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/SO79280659

Thanks, but that doesn't work here either. I've tried other rendermodes and SyncFusions NuGet package, but they all crash. I've deleted .vs folder and tried a bunch a new projects, but nothing seems to help. Must be something squirrely in my VS or something.

I still don't know what that was about, but after a complete reinstallation of VS things finally work. Thanks a lot for the project and helpful questions!

Turns out the culprit was the Brave browser. Reinstalling VS set Chrome as default browser, and it started working again. When I chose Brave (my actual default browser) for debugging, the same problem came back.

interesting. Would be interesting to communicate this to Brave dev team somehow - unsure how's the proper way.
